# Use of pronouns

Tags: personal-pronouns

I saw in many websites that native English speakers obviate the pronouns, but I don't know when I can do that.

Example:
I like it, love it and enjoy it!

Instead of:
I like it, I love it and I enjoy it!

In my school taught me that you have to use always this pronouns.

Comment: It's nothing special about pronouns: you can do the exact same thing with nouns: My cat hunts mice, plays with yarn, and likes to sleep in the sun.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a rule or something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pronoun “you” can be omitted as subject in imperative form, what other pronouns can be omitted, when and why?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95808/pronoun-you-can-be-omitted-as-subject-in-imperative-form-what-other-pronouns)

Comment: On a side note: you are leaving out the [oxford comma](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oxford-comma).  It should be "I like it, love it, and enjoy it!"

Answer (score 2):

The first example, the model you wish to emulate, is a **simple sentence with a compound predicate**.  It is substantially similar to

> ***Wilhelmina bought some oysters, pried them open, and ate them with gusto.***

One subject does three things. Replacing Wilhelmina with a prounoun changes nothing grammatically.

The teacher who favored the second construction grasps **compound sentences,** but may not be comfortable with compound elements within sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Either way is grammatically correct. People prefer to avoid the second "I" in writing because it's more concise, but like to put it in when speaking, especially informally because it makes it easier for the listener to follow. You could also avoid using "it" more than once: "I like, love and enjoy it".